# Unexpected generics behaviour

Tags: java, generics

I found strange generics behaviour. In two words -
thing I realy want is to use ComplexObject1 in most general way, and the thing I realy missed is why defined generic type(... extends BuisnessObject) is lost.
The discuss thread is also awailable in my blog 
http://pronicles.blogspot.com/2010/03/unexpected-generics-behaviour.html.

```
public class Test {

  public interface EntityObject {}

  public interface SomeInterface {}

  public class BasicEntity implements EntityObject {}

  public interface BuisnessObject<E extends EntityObject> {
    E getEntity();
  }

  public interface ComplexObject1<V extends SomeInterface> extends BuisnessObject<BasicEntity> {}

  public interface ComplexObject2 extends BuisnessObject<BasicEntity> {}

  public void test(){
    ComplexObject1 complexObject1 = null;
    ComplexObject2 complexObject2 = null;

    EntityObject entityObject1 = complexObject1.getEntity();
    //BasicEntity entityObject1 = complexObject1.getEntity(); wtf incompatible types!!!!
    BasicEntity basicEntity = complexObject2.getEntity();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using a raw type of `ComplexObject1`. It's easy to fix: just use `ComplexObject1<?>` instead, and your code compiles fine.

There's really nothing unexpected about this behavior at all.

From the [tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html):

> Type erasure exists so that new code may continue to interface with legacy code. *Using a raw type for any other reason is considered bad programming practice and should be avoided whenever possible.*

From [JLS 4.8 Raw Types](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.8) (emphasis theirs):

> The use of raw types is allowed only as a concession to compatibility of legacy code. The use of raw types in code written after the introduction of genericity into the Java programming language is strongly discouraged. **It is possible that future versions of the Java programming language will disallow the use of raw types.**

See also *Effective Java 2nd Edition*, Item 23: Don't use raw type in new code.

Answer (score 1):

Basically if a class has generic arguments and you declare it without those parameters, it is a raw type. Raw types lose generic arguments in their members.

See [What is the raw type?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ201)

> #### What is the raw type?
>
> ***The generic type without any type arguments.***
>
> The generic type without any type
>   arguments, like `Collection`, is
>   called *raw type*.

and [Can I use a raw type like any other type?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ203)

> Methods or constructors of a raw type
>   have the signature that they would
>   have after type erasure.

This confuses people in corner cases. For example:

```
public interface MyClass<T> {
  T foo();
  List<String> bar();
}

MyClass m = ...
List<String> list = m.bar(); // warning!
```

It confuses people because the return type of this method has nothing to do with the generic type argument but that's how Java works.